# Modificar valores de fila en base a datos provenientes de otro DataFrame (Como si trabajara con FK)

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo dos DataFrame:

(Pongo ejemplo simples)

El primero es el de la informacion donde estoy trabajando:

**Nombre de dataframe detalleCompleto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo es de la tabla desde donde sale el nombre del detalle de la clave foranea de la tabla anterior del campo DETALLE:

*En la tabla anterior en la columna DETALLE el 1 seria Acompañamiento y Contención*

**Nombre de dataframe detalle**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora estuve viendo que se pueden cambiar los nombres de las columnas en base a nombre que vengan de otro archivo, pero, se pueden cambiar valores de filas en base a su relación con otro DataFrame.

Por el momento lo hice así:

```
df['detalleCompleto'].replace(
   to_replace= [1,2,3,4,5],
    value= ['Acompañamiento y Contención', 'Ajustes', 'Anclaje', 
    'Asesoramiento','Automatismos'],
    inplace=True
)
```

Pero al ser cambiantes los datos y como siempre me llegan esos dos archivos me sirve mas hacerlo una sola vez y que vaya, lea los archivos y haga las modificaciones sin que yo tenga que ir agregando o quitando información.

Y es info que tengo:

```
idDetalle = detalle['IDDETALLE']
idDetalle
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
detalle = detalle['DETALLE']
detalle
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas tiene un método `merge()` pensado para mezclar dataframes como si fueran tablas de una base de datos, tal como necesitas.

Si estos son tus dataframes:

df:

```html
   detalle  id  perdida  total
0        1   1        2     10
1        2   2        3     20
2        3   3        4     30
3        4   4        5     40
4        5   5        6     50
```

detalle:

```html
                       detalle  iddetalle
0  Acompañamiento y Contención          1
1                      Ajustes          2
2                      Anclaje          3
3                Asesoramiento          4
4                 Automatismos          5
```

Y los mezclas así:

```
pd.merge(df, detalle, left_on="detalle", right_on="iddetalle")
```

el resultado es éste:

```html
   detalle_x  id  perdida  total                    detalle_y  iddetalle
0          1   1        2     10  Acompañamiento y Contención          1
1          2   2        3     20                      Ajustes          2
2          3   3        4     30                      Anclaje          3
3          4   4        5     40                Asesoramiento          4
4          5   5        6     50                 Automatismos          5
```

Ya que los dataframes originales tenían ambos una columna llamada `detalle`, para diferenciarlas tras la mezcla las ha renombrado automáticamente como `detalle_x` (la que venía de la primera tabla) y `detalle_y` (la que venía de la segunda). El resto de columnas son las que tenían las tablas originales, y el "join" lo ha hecho en base a las columnas `"detalle"` de la primera tabla y `"detalleid"` de la segunda.

Ahora, si quieres, puedes eliminar las columnas que te sobran y renombrar la que tiene la descripción. Puedes combinarlo todo en una sola expresión:

```
df = (pd.merge(df, detalle, left_on="detalle", right_on="iddetalle")
   .drop(["detalle_x", "iddetalle"], axis=1)
   .rename(columns={"detalle_y": "detalleCompleto"})
)
```

Lo que teja `df` así:

```html
   id  perdida  total              detalleCompleto
0   1        2     10  Acompañamiento y Contención
1   2        3     20                      Ajustes
2   3        4     30                      Anclaje
3   4        5     40                Asesoramiento
4   5        6     50                 Automatismos
```

## Ampliación de respuesta

En un caso más práctico raro será que las tablas `df`  y `detalle` tengan el mismo número de filas. Si, por ejemplo, la tabla `detalle` tiene sólo dos elementos de `idddetalle` 1 y 2, así:

```html
                        detalle  iddetalle
0  Acompañamiento y Contención          1
1                      Ajustes          2
```

Y la tabla `df` repite números en la columna `detalle`, así:

```html
   detalle  id  perdida  total
0        1   1        2     10
1        2   2        3     20
2        2   3        4     30
3        1   4        5     40
4        1   5        6     50
```

El resultado del `merge` antes expuesto daría el siguiente resultado, similar al que produciría un JOIN de SQL:

```html
   id  perdida  total              detalleCompleto
   1        2     10  Acompañamiento y Contención
   2        3     20                      Ajustes
   3        4     30                      Ajustes
   4        5     40  Acompañamiento y Contención
   5        6     50  Acompañamiento y Contención
```

¡Cuidado! Si en la tabla `df` aparece alguna fila con un detalle cuyo id no está en la otra tabla, esa fila desaparecerá del resultado del `merge`.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, tuve errores pero era por el encoding de una de los archivos, pero solucionando eso ya hace el merge ok.